# SSIS Data Flow fails ONLY when inside Foreach Loop Container

Tags: ssis

I have SSIS Data Flow Task (with a Flat File Source, a Derived Column and an OLE DB Destination) which runs without error when I run it on it's own using execute task.

When I put the data flow inside a foreach loop container the flat file source fails with a truncation error on the SAME file.

What could the issue be?

Comment: Need more info bro. What's the error message? Do you have any sort of transactions turned on for the container.

Comment: Do you have DelayValidation set to False? and your variables mapped in in your Expressions property of the Flat File Source Connection editor?  Also the truncation error could be do to outside metadata or might need to go into the advance editor and fix its size or type.